# How to manage elements with the same class in a method of Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi Im using a Jquery method to highlight areas of a map. (called maphilight)

The next method highlight a single piece of area when I click on it.

```
$('.key').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
    data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
    $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
});
```

All the areas have the class of "key" and some of them have also the class of "alpha" or "control".

Now the problem is when I want to highligh with this jquery some areas at the same time using a button("balpha"). For example I want to highlight the areas with the class "alpha".

Then Im using the next method.

```
$('#balpha').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('.alpha').mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
    data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
    $('.alpha').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
});
```

When I do this, all the areas with the class "alpha" are highlighted and when I press it again they turn off without problem. The problem is that when I try to do it individually after using the class "alpha" all the areas work as one and get all highlighted when I try to manage then one by one.

I think that its a problem with the variable "data" but I dont know how to manage it. Thank in advice :)

Here is a sample of the code that show my results, hope its help to get a solution!!! thanks again!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Keyboard Designer</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/jquery.maphilight.js"></script>
<!-- hiligh jQuery implementation -->
<script>$(function() {
    $('.map').maphilight({
        fillColor: '008800'
    });

    <!-- function choose individual keycap -->
    $('.key').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
        data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
        $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });
    <!--function to choose alphanumerics-->
    $('#balpha').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $('.alpha').mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
        data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
        $('.alpha').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });
});</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YY2VAs8.png" width="980" height="292" alt="applekeyboard" class="map" usemap="#appleKeyboard">
        <map name="appleKeyboard">
        <!-- alphanumeric buttoms -->
        <area shape="rect" coords="61,58,98,95" href="#" alt="n1" class="key alpha" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"0000ff","strokeWidth":2,"fillColor":"ff0000","fillOpacity":0.0}'>
        <area shape="rect" coords="104,58,141,95" href="#" alt="n2" class="key alpha" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"0000ff","strokeWidth":2,"fillColor":"ff0000","fillOpacity":0.0}'>
        <area shape="rect" coords="147,58,184,95" href="#" alt="n3" class="key alpha" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"0000ff","strokeWidth":2,"fillColor":"ff0000","fillOpacity":0.0}'>
        <area shape="rect" coords="190,58,227,95" href="#" alt="n4" class="key alpha" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"0000ff","strokeWidth":2,"fillColor":"ff0000","fillOpacity":0.0}'>
    </map>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>keys group</legend>
            <button id="balpha" type="button" value="alpha" >Alphanumeric</button><br />
    </fieldset>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to see the html for this.

Comment: Provide a sample fiddle in order to reproduce your results.

Comment: Hi, added the sample of the code that reproduce my result, if you could take a look would be would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample to reproduce my results.

And this is the Jquery im using: http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/jquery.maphilight.js

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Keyboard Designer</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

$(function() {
       $('.map').maphilight({
           fillColor: '008800'
        });

```
    <!-- function choose individual keycap -->
     $('.key').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var data = $(this).mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
         data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
         $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });
    <!--function to choose alphanumerics-->
    $('#balpha').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $('.alpha').mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
        data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
        $('.alpha').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YY2VAs8.png" width="980" height="292" alt="applekeyboard" class="map" usemap="#appleKeyboard">
    <map name="appleKeyboard">
    <!-- alphanumeric buttoms -->
    <area shape="rect" coords="61,58,98,95" href="#" alt="n1" class="key alpha" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"0000ff","strokeWidth":2,"fillColor":"ff0000","fillOpacity":0.0}'>
    <area shape="rect" coords="104,58,141,95" href="#" alt="n2" class="key alpha" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"0000ff","strokeWidth":2,"fillColor":"ff0000","fillOpacity":0.0}'>
    <area shape="rect" coords="147,58,184,95" href="#" alt="n3" class="key alpha" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"0000ff","strokeWidth":2,"fillColor":"ff0000","fillOpacity":0.0}'>
    <area shape="rect" coords="190,58,227,95" href="#" alt="n4" class="key alpha" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"0000ff","strokeWidth":2,"fillColor":"ff0000","fillOpacity":0.0}'>
</map>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>keys group</legend>
            <button id="balpha" type="button" value="alpha" >Alphanumeric
            </button><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Once you youse the alphanumeric button the button 1,2,3,4 doesnt work individually and works as one to be chosen.

Comment: This should be an edit to the *question*, not a separate answer. Click on the edit link (below the tags of your question) and add this information there.